# Sticky bar with filter button and product count

Tags: plugin-development, functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, theme-customizer

I use elementor and hello theme. I need to create a sticky bar with filter button and product count when you scroll product archive, similar to https://www.chanel.com/it/make-up/labbra/c/5x1x1x31/rossetti/